# Encrypt Entity Model with Entity Framework Core

Tags: mariadb, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a project where security matters on a number of fields in my Entity Models. I'm looking for a way I might be able to inject some custom logic with EF Core (with a MariaDb SQL Server) to encrypt data going into the database and decrypt it as it comes out automatically. Essentially I'm looking to do something similar to the following where I may have a field that contains sensitive information that could be either a string or DateTime in my model, but needs to be as an encrypted string in the database.

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Secure]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Secure]
    public string StateIdNumber { get; set; }

    public List<CreditCard> CreditCards { get; set; }
}

public class CreditCard
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Secure]
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }

    [Secure]
    public DateTime Expiration { get; set; }

    [Secure]
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So your main attack vector is someone stealing your database?

Comment: The concern in the case is someone actually accessing the database yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2016, you can use the [Always Encrypted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt757097.aspx) feature. (I'm not sure if *MariaDb SQL Server* is a hosted version of Microsoft SQL Server or a different database entirely...)

Comment: MariaDb is a off shoot of MySQL